# JQuery 2-modal Conflict: Need to "remove" animatedModal, but with DELAY, to hide scrollbar for 2nd modal

Tags: jquery, onclick, modal-dialog, delay

I have 2 different type of modals on a page. One is an 'animatedModal' which triggers on page load, and the other is a standard modal that fires onclick of a button.

For the 2nd one, since it pops open a video, I had to add a hide double scrollbar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.pop-open').click(function() {a
        $('body').css({
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        });
    });
$('.lightbox').click(function() {
        $('body').css({
        'overflow': 'visible',
        });
    });
});
```

However, the first (animatedModal) script conflicts. The hide double scrollbar only works when I add this, to remove the first modal (after it's closed):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".survey-close").on("click", function(e) {
     $("#animatedModal").remove();
 });
});
```

It works, but the issue is **I lose the outro animation of the animatedModal** because it closes too abruptly. So I tried to simply add a delay on the remove script. It didn't work.

So my question is either:

**a) How do I add a delay to the remove script above?

b) Or alternately, how do I put the remove into the animatedModal script when it closes?**

Here's the animatedModal script in case choice b is easier:

```
(function ($) {
 
    $.fn.animatedModal = function(options) {
        var modal = $(this);
        
        //Defaults
        var settings = $.extend({
            modalTarget:'animatedModal', 
            position:'fixed', 
            width:'100%', 
            height:'100%', 
            top:'0px', 
            left:'0px', 
            zIndexIn: '9999',  
            zIndexOut: '-9999',  
            color: 'rgba(250,250,250,0.5)', 
            opacityIn:'1',  
            opacityOut:'0', 
            animatedIn:'lightSpeedIn',
            animatedOut:'bounceOut',
            animationDuration:'.6s', 
            //overflow:'auto', 
            // Callbacks
            beforeOpen: function() {},           
            afterOpen: function() {}, 
            beforeClose: function() {}, 
            afterClose: function() {}
 
            

        }, options);
        
        var closeBt = $('.close-'+settings.modalTarget);

        //console.log(closeBt)

        var href = $(modal).attr('href'),
            id = $('body').find('#'+settings.modalTarget),
            idConc = '#'+id.attr('id');
            //console.log(idConc);
            // Default Classes
            id.addClass('animated');
            id.addClass(settings.modalTarget+'-off');

        //Init styles
        var initStyles = {
            'position':settings.position,
            'width':settings.width,
            'height':settings.height,
            'top':settings.top,
            'left':settings.left,
            'background-color':settings.color,
            //'overflow-y':settings.overflow,
            'z-index':settings.zIndexOut,
            'opacity':settings.opacityOut,
            '-webkit-animation-duration':settings.animationDuration
        };
        //Apply stles
        id.css(initStyles);

        modal.click(function(event) {       
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body, html').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
            if (href == idConc) {
                if (id.hasClass(settings.modalTarget+'-off')) {
                    id.removeClass(settings.animatedOut);
                    id.removeClass(settings.modalTarget+'-off');
                    id.addClass(settings.modalTarget+'-on');
                } 

                 if (id.hasClass(settings.modalTarget+'-on')) {
                    settings.beforeOpen();
                    id.css({'opacity':settings.opacityIn,'z-index':settings.zIndexIn});
                    id.addClass(settings.animatedIn);  
                    id.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', afterOpen);
                };  
            } 
        });



        closeBt.click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body, html').css({'overflow':'auto'});

            settings.beforeClose(); //beforeClose
            if (id.hasClass(settings.modalTarget+'-on')) {
                id.removeClass(settings.modalTarget+'-on');
                id.addClass(settings.modalTarget+'-off');
            } 

            if (id.hasClass(settings.modalTarget+'-off')) {
                id.removeClass(settings.animatedIn);
                id.addClass(settings.animatedOut);
                id.one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', afterClose);
            };

        });

        function afterClose () {       
            id.css({'z-index':settings.zIndexOut});
            settings.afterClose(); //afterClose
        }

        function afterOpen () {       
            settings.afterOpen(); //afterOpen
        }

    }; // End animatedModal.js

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the delay use setTimeout function. Note: just hide the modal.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#animatedModal").hide(); }, 5000);//5 secs delay
setTimeout(function(){ $("#animatedModal").modal("hide"); }, 5000);//using bootstrap modal
```

Use [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/) events,

```
$('#animatedModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

Comment: Hi Ian. :) I appreciate the reply. I tried that first code already but it didn't work. I'm confused by your second thing. What does that do? Edit: oh I think you're saying to totally change to a new modal? I can't. I have everything focused around what I'm currently using. All I need is a timeout for making animatedModal remove on close.

Comment: Hi Brandydoll, you're most welcome :) the hidden.bs.modal means "This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete)." thats when the modal was closed. instead of using click event on .survey-close class.

Comment: ok I'm super excited to try this tomorrow! I tried for 7 hours by myself... ugh. :x Will post back to say if it worked... (and TYSM for adding the exact detailed code with delay!!)

Comment: By the way are you saying do it like this: $('#animatedModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#animatedModal").remove(); }, 5000);//5 secs delay
});

Comment: yes, and don't use $("#animatedModal").remove(), use $("#animatedModal").hide() and $("#animatedModal").show() to display. use $("#animatedModal").modal("hide") for bootstrap modal.

Comment: if you're not using bootstrap modal, then use setTimeout(function(){ $("#animatedModal").hide(); }, 5000); inside the $(".survey-close").on("click".

Comment: Hi ian, thank you so much for trying. <3 :) I'm sure if you had access to my page we could have made it work. I tried for hours, but nothing took so I ended up posting an answer of what I used for a workaround. If you have time, can you tell me how to put 2 selectors in my very first script up top, instead of .lightbox? I tried this but it didn't work: $('.close-x, .close-btn').click(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nothing worked to create a timeout on this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".survey-close").on("click", function(e) {
     $("#animatedModal").remove();
 });
});
```

It does work to kill the modal when pressing my specified button, but the issue is that I was losing the outro animation of the modal that was being killed. So unless I could successfully add a timeout, I can't use it.

So the workaround I ended up using, is to simply change this, in the animatedModal script itself:

```
closeBt.click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body, html').css({'overflow':'auto'});
```

To:

```
closeBt.click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body, html').css({'overflow':''});  //removed auto
```

This allowed my hide double scrollbar script for the second modal to finally work, and removed the conflict. Changing the overflow in animatedModal script after close, gets me to my core objective: getting hide double scroll (from my OP) to work.

I'm sure this all sounds convoluted but maybe somebody using animatedModal + another popup, who's fanatic about double scrollbars, will find it useful one day.